# Retrieve GTM code from database and display in angularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several websites that use an AngularJS app. Each website has different GTM tracking. I'm storing the tracking code in our database. Eg:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXX"
                height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>
    <script>
(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
}); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXX');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

In my angular app, I've retrieved the code, but how do I go about inserting it into my HTML?
I tried:

```
<div id="tracking">
    {{tracking}}
</div>
```

but this displays the code on the screen.

Comment: Please post more code... How do you assign tracking variable ? Where is your ng-app, ng-controller ? What do you do in controller ? The google tag manager is out of the controller scope, how do you retrieve the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the solution is to use the $sce service. Example here: http://erikaugust.com/thoughts/ng-bind-html/

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

instead of

```
<div id="tracking">
    {{tracking}}
</div>
```

you write that

```
<div ng-bind-html="tracking">
</div>
```

in script you must do

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

and inject in the module

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Comment: I have just tried this by putting the GTM code into a scope variable to test. I got no errors, but when I inspect the HTML, I can see the ng-bind-html DIV, but the script code isn't inside. I even tried with a simple <script>var a='123';</script> and this doesn't appear either.